# iOS push/pop viewcontrollers memory still increases

Tags: ios, xcode, memory

I'm testing memory for my iPhone app. xcode 4.2.1, ios 5.0+, using ARC

I have two view controllers. The first one has a grid of UIButtons, and the second view controller has detailed information about the button the user touches. I'm using a push segue.

I'm using the mark heap tool to measure heap growth. I touch a button, then click back, and then click "mark heap" and I did this a few times. My mark heap growth is between 1-2 mb for each of my heapshots.

I'm expecting the heap growth to be zero though. In a more detailed description, I see the heap growth is due to non-object. I've used the leaks tool, and it doesn't show any leaked memory.

**What could be the reason for the heap growth? How do I fix it?**

**What does it even mean to pop a UIViewController? When I click the back button in the navigation bar, does it completely delete the UIViewController and release the UIViewController and subviews from memory? Or do I need to do something manually?**

Thanks! I'm puzzled...

Comment: "In a more detailed description, I see the heap growth is due to . " -- you skipped something here...

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are not creating objects of the next page class each time when you hit button. use check like if(!objVC) then do something..

This will make allocation of your class only once and ofcource you have to manage data of your objects on the next page on viewWillDisappear of viewDIdUnload.